# if form field input is empty than do not update in database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form with 8 input fields. Now I don't want to update a field in the database if it's left empty.

This are the fields that I like to check. if empty do not update them and leave the original value. How to do this?

This is my function in my controller

```
function update_profile(){

    $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'telefoon' => $this->input->post('telefoon'),
            'gsm' => $this->input->post('gsm'),
            'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
            'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
            'portfolio' => $this->input->post('portfolio'),
            'profilefoto' => $this->input->post('browse')
            );
    $this->kdg_model->update_profile($data);
}
```

My model

```
function update_profile($data) {
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('user');
    $this->db->where('user', $session_id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the field from your main `array` and check it in a different way.

Let's assume that this is your `$data` array:

```
$data = array(
    'naam' => $this->input->post('naam'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'telefoon' => $this->input->post('telefoon'),
    'gsm' => $this->input->post('gsm'),
    'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
    'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
    'portfolio' => $this->input->post('portfolio'),
    'profielfoto' => $this->input->post('browse')
);
```

and about `not_update_if_blank`, all you need to do is check it after the `$data` array:

```
if( $this->input->post('not_update_if_blank') != "" )
{
    $data['not_update_if_blank'] = $this->input->post('not_update_if_blank');
}
```

now you can pass `$data` to your model.

EDIT:

```
$post_array = $this->input->post();
foreach( $post_array as $key=>$value )
{
    if(trim($value)!= "")
    {
       $data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

now pass `$data` to your model.
NB: test the code because I haven't tested it!

Comment: ok works, but do i have to do this for every field in a separate if() or can i use a loop to get all fields in one time?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the best solution near me is To Validate the form, but if you still want to avoid validation than go like this: Its the simplest way, not good but simplest:

E.g

```
if($name!='' && $email!='' && $facebook!='') //place all your Post variables here same like these 3 variables.
{

//Perform your Updation process here.

}
```